# Windows set maximum number of threads in default thread pool

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

Starting with Windows Vista, every application automatically gets a [thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-pools) (the "default thread pool").

**My Question is**: is there a way to configure the min and max number of threads for this **default thread pool**?

[`SetThreadpoolThreadMaximum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-setthreadpoolthreadmaximum?redirectedfrom=MSDN) seems to work only for a **non-default thread pool** (a pool created with [`CreateThreadpool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-createthreadpool?redirectedfrom=MSDN)):

`SetThreadpoolThreadMaximum(NULL, 4);` - throws `0xC000000D: An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Joe Duffy from Microsoft, this is not possible.

Here's a quote from his book, [Concurrent Programming on Windows](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Concurrent_Programming_on_Windows.html?id=EV73mAEACAAJ), chapter 7. Thread Pools, page [345](https://books.google.fr/books?id=o4ohrd0_yA0C&pg=PT318&dq=%22not%20possible%20to%20alter%20the%20default%20thread%20pool%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBsfmo9InrAhVMzhoKHXOkDLcQuwUwAHoECAQQBw#v=onepage&q=%22not%20possible%20to%20alter%20the%20default%20thread%20pool%22&f=false):

> Note that it is not possible to alter the default thread pool's
> minimum and maximum count; instead, you must specify a pointer to a
> custom `TP_POOL` object. Prior to Vista, you could change the
> process-wide default pool's maximum (as we see later). The reason this
> capability has been removed is because it depends on races: the last
> component to call the API would win. This can cause conflicts between
> components in the same process that are unaware of each other but want
> different maximum or minimum values.

The "old way" of increasing the pool size the author is referring to is the macro `WT_SET_MAX_THREADPOOL_THREADS`, used in [`QueueUserWorkItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoollegacyapiset/nf-threadpoollegacyapiset-queueuserworkitem?redirectedfrom=MSDN). That setting seems to be ignored in the new pool architecture.

So the default pool's minimum is fixed at 0 and the maximum is 500.